# Circle progress default is 85 but output shows 0

Tags: geometry, progress-bar, ionic4

I am adding a circle progress bar.

The default value of the bar is 85% but it shows 0% output.

Installed with:

```
npm i ng-circle-progress
```

Using:

```
<circle-progress [percent]="85" [radius]="100" [outerStrokeWidth]="16" [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'" [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'" [animation]="true" [animationDuration]="300">
</circle-progress>
```

It is working in angular but not in Ionic 4.

Comment: Do you think you gave enough info for any body to seek for your issue? Please, take a look at [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Actually, there was a little bit more hidden in there because op did not format their code correctly. Still not much better though... :)

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an error in your console log which will give you a hint of what's going wrong.

As a test, you should remove the `[animation]="true"` which could be trying to reference some incompatible files. If that is the case then [there is a workaround](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues/48#issuecomment-456020770).